# How can I get rid of the first if statement from this function?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that checks if an input is even or not. There are some preset conditions for what it must output, for example both the number 42 and string "42" should read as even. Here is the code I have:

```
function isEven (inputEven) {
  if (inputEven === false) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    inputEven = Number(inputEven);
    if (inputEven%2 === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see at the start of the function I have an if statement to check if the input is the boolean false. I had to do this as if my function is given that without that if statement it will give back true while my requirement sheet says it needs to give back false. Is there any way to simplify this down to a single if/else statement?

Comment: what should it return for 0?

Comment: 0 should return true

Comment: Your function returns true for the empty string. I have made my answer to do the same. But is that really intended?

Comment: It does not state what it should return for that, nor does the testing script check for that so I am not sure.

Comment: OK, then allow me to update my answer...

Comment: How do you want the result to be for "0xE" and "0xF", "0b100" and "0b101"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns true for an empty string. You wrote in comments that it should in fact return false in that case. So I had to update my answer after getting that info:

But first: it is almost never needed to have a pattern like this:

```
if (something) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

You can just return the value of `something` in that case, possibly converted to boolean.

In your case all can be brought down to the following:

```
function isEven(inputEven) {
    return inputEven !== false && inputEven !== "" && (Number(inputEven)%2===0);
}
```

Comment: but that returns `true` when passed `false`.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I have added the condition for it.

Answer (score 5):

try using `parseInt` instead.

```js
function isEven (inputEven) {
 var val = parseInt(inputEven, 10);
 return (!isNaN(val) && val%2 === 0);
}

console.log('empty', isEven());
console.log("''", isEven(''));
console.log('true', isEven(true));
console.log('false', isEven(false));
console.log("'dogs'", isEven('dogs'));
console.log("'true'", isEven('true'));
console.log("'false'", isEven('false'));
console.log('0', isEven(0));
console.log('1', isEven(1));
console.log('2', isEven(2));
console.log("'3'", isEven('3'));
console.log("'4'", isEven('4'));
```

Comment: can be simplified further to `return (parseInt(inputEven, 10) % 2) === 0`

Comment: This returns true for 4.5... The OP's code doesn't.

Comment: You can always change it to `parseFloat()` to handle floating-point values. I just didn't think it was needed since the question showed only whole numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using:

```
function isEven (inputEven) {
  return parseFloat(inputEven)%2 === 0;
}
```

Which meets all of the requirements for the test script.